# Cant get my site to be responsive - doesnt seem to be recognising style sheet

Tags: css

SO i have designed my first site for a desktop and it works fine on desktop.

I am trying to re-design this for mobile/make it responsive.

I am doing this u=by using the style sheet and putting a condition in.

here is the condition:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    
    body{
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

However, when i do this i cant get anything to change for a iphone x (or anything else with a width of 375)

my style sheet is still linked fine - i can change the background on the desktop site fine. I cannot change anything only on the mobile site using this code so im guessing it is something to do wiith the media tag.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it a caching issue? Try opening the browsers developer tools `F12`, then opening the mobile tools `Ctrl-Shift-M`.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 0):

#### Making webpages responsive using `max-width`

Try this:

```css
body {
  background-color: tan;
}

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue.  */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive This should work for your iPhone */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

This should look like this:

[image: This should work like this]

Also, make sure this exists in your HTML:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

you can check if you have put this statement or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {

body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

everything looks good, I guess you have css specificity issue,
try to add !important like,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    
    body{
        background-color: red!important;
    }
}
```

and try to use responsive things in the neath of CSS styles.

Comment: Adding `!important` to force CSS behaviour without troubleshooting why it does not work without doing so... will cause future you to curse that approach.

Comment: imagine if the user use `html body{}` like or if the user uses responsive things above the body selector then it's the cause of specificity of using that kind of behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is ok for testing to see if it works, but then research why before just implementing the override. So, check out the element using dev tools and determine (instead of imagine) any specificity issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me, but you might want to consider using this instead:

```css
@media (orientation:portrait){
  body{
    background-color:red;
  }
}
```

Don't forget about css specificity. For testing, the devtools in firefox are pretty good. You can simulate a phone by pressing Ctrl+Shift+M. It's called responsive Design mode and is made precisely for situations like yours where it's not 100% clear what is causing the problem.